# What's causing this optical effect around flying plane captured on Google maps?

Tags: optics

I am unable to get my head around what is causing this optical effect. Which is caused when satellite captured this image of a flying plane.

<kbd>**[Location on Google maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps/@19.2030979,72.9123561,100m/data=!3m1!1e3)**</kbd>

[image]

I found this **[explanation](https://thenextweb.com/google/2017/07/25/google-maps-accidentally-caught-satellite-image-airplane-mid-flight/#.tnw_zubJ4ccr)** online but it doesn't seem to be very much adept.

Comment: Could you please include in the question the explanation you linked and why you're not convinced by it?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said this is not chromatic aberration.  Instead it's an artifact of the way the cameras in satellites work (links below).  They do not work like a conventional 'domestic' digital camera, which uses a single sensor and a single exposure to make a colour image.  Instead they have a panchromatic imaging system which captures high-resolution, luminance-only (ie B/W) images, and several systems which capture, typically lower-resolution, images in various wavelengths.  All of these systems 'look through' the same telescope.

So colour images from a satellite like this are put together from several images, which are *not made simultaneously* in general.  So fast-moving objects, like planes, exhibit all sorts of weird artifacts, as can be seen in the image in the question.

Links:

- [WorldView-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WorldView-4) is a current Earth-observation satellite;
- [some more detailed information](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/675) on the satellite;
- [information on the imaging system](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/678).

Answer (score 2):

The plane is very bright and the ground is relatively dark, making the chromatic aberration of the telescope imaging system, which is always present, highly visible.

The form of this is specific to the optics of the telescope.

Comment: Could you come up with a reasonable optical system that would have this kind of 1D chromatic aberration? I imagine you would need to have a prism somewhere, and that there is an internal surface reflection that causes an additional pass through the prism resulting in a faint "echo" with a shift. I can't get over the fact that the colored image appears "in the past of the plane".  Some latent image on the sensor from the previous exposure (saturation) seems more likely to me.

Comment: @Floris You do not know that the colored image appears "in the past" of the plane.  You only know that it appears somewhat to the left of, and just slightly below the plane in the image's coordinate system.  The fact that that the displacement is approximately opposite the plane's heading could be a coincidence.  If the cause of the displacement is a defect in the telescope's optical system, then it would be somewhat to the left and just slightly below regardless of the direction of the plane's flight.

Comment: @jameslarge I don't disagree with you. That is why I said "appears" in my comment - which I think is clearly worded as speculative. I have a hard time conceiving of an optical system with this kind of aberration - so I make some observations hoping this will spark further conversation. "Regular" chromatic aberration shows up as fringing - this image is displaced which requires more careful explanation.

Comment: On the other hand, the satellite may be doing some kind of multi-spectral imaging.  It's possible that the image you see in Google maps was reconstructed from two or more images that were acquired by different cameras at slightly different times and, that the rainbow shadow is an artifact of an algorithm that corrects for the motion of the satellite, but not the motion of the plane.  I looked at other bright white objects (rooftops) in the near by city, and I did not see any trace of the same effect.

Comment: Here's another:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hv1OMtI0xGGIVrfx6msOjRcSDJw&usp=sharing  In this case, it's very obvious that the color image was reconstructed from four separate single-color images that were snapped just milliseconds apart.  What's puzzling in _this_ map though, is that the plane's image is enormous compared to the houses below.  That would not be the case if it was snapped by a satellite hundreds of miles up.  Maybe the images in this area were captured by another aircraft.

Comment: @Floris - The prism would likely be edge of the lens. I would guess the plane is off center, near the edge. Light reflects of the sensor, off the top surface of the lens, an goes back down to the sensor.